# Maximum length of cable for a 144Hz monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, displayport

I have just picked up 3xASUS VG248QE monitors that can run at 1920x1080@144Hz but I am having trouble finding what the maximum length of cable which officially supports the required length.

Due to the vagaries of my home office/games den the distance from my PC to the furthest monitor is about 2.2 metres directly but taking into account routing of the cables it works out about 3.60 metres.  I could knock about 40-50cm off that but then it would impede airflow around the computer.

Looking at Amazon most cut and paste the descriptions for 2m all the way up to 10m.  Most don't do a 4m skipping from 3m to 5m.

What are the official maximum lengths (DVI/DisplayPort) for running at 144Hz?

If the standard doesn't support that resolution & freq for that distance what's it like in practice?  Is it pot luck?

Also would DVI or DisplayPort be better for this distance?

Answer (score 0):

This is more based on the standards for the interface than what you're transmitting, although in all cases, lower resolutions and refresh rates are going to hold together better over longer distances.

The standards give you a baseline. DVI doesn't actually have a standard range, which is why you're having trouble finding one.  A general rule of thumb is that if you want 1080p across DVI at roughly 60hz, you don't want to go more than 15 ft. At 144hz, if the video source can broadcast at that refresh rate, I would limit your cable to 7-10 ft.  I can tell you that I have two monitors connected via DVI-Dual Link that are on 10 ft cables, doing 1920x1080@120hz, and I experience absolutely no signal degradation that is human perceptible.  Dual Link cables and transmission are required to get that kind of quality, however.

Displayport gives you more options.  You can connect it to an optic fiber line to vastly increase the distance the signal can travel, and it also holds together a bit better without doing that because it is capable of adjusting amplitude.  This means that if you go over the standard full bandwidth connection speed cap of roughly 10 ft (1080p @ 60hz), it scales down the transmission bandwidth to allow stable connections up to nearly 50ft.  Following similar rules, I'd say 5-7ft for full bandwidth at your refresh rate, 25ft or so to prevent performance degradation at half bandwidth.

In all cases, broadcasting equipment and receiving equipment quality play a big role in actual results.  You can get no more than 5 ft @ full bandwidth on a DP connection with a cheap source and a cheap destination, or you can get over 10ft with good cables and equipment.  The same goes for DVI: If you are using a dual-link connection, you get more options than normal for refresh rates and resolution, and with good quality cables and transmission source you can experience no changes well above the average anecdotal length limits.